# NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter' is not defined

Tags: vb.net, dll, pdf-generation

Hi this may sound like a dumb question, but I am trying to use the NReco PDF library in my VB.NET Win Form application, and I am getting this error when I try to compile my code:

***NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter' is not defined***

I added the reference to the DLL and when I first wrote this code:

```
Dim converter As New NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter
```

It recognized the NReco namespace and everything seemed fine, but whenever I try to compile it acts like the DLL is missing. I know this library is written in C# but the site just said it was a .NET library, and I have used other libraries written in C# with no problem.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

[image: I did also confirm with solution explorer that the DLL is there.]

Comment: Does the DLL show in Solution Explorer? (Show All Files -> expand References)

Comment: Yes @Plutonix I did confirm that and posted a screenshot.

Comment: Cannot repro - Dowloaded the stuff, unzipped, added reference, added `Imports` added that one line of code, compiled to `AnyCPU Release` and `x86 Debug` without error.  Maybe try to restart VS?

Comment: Plutonix could you show me what Imports statement you added?

Comment: I've tried restarting VS and cleaning my project many times with no luck.

Comment: well, based on your line of code, I used `Imports NReco`.  if I use `Imports NReco.PdfGenerator` then `Dim cvt As New HtmlToPdfConverter` is all that is needed.  The latter is all that is really needed since NReco is just a NameSpace

Comment: That's the same import that I did. Did you try and compile the code though?

Comment: comment 3: *compiled to `AnyCPU Release` and `x86 Debug` without error*. the compiled EXE also runs without error,  I am not doing anything with the converter, just instancing it.  Maybe the error is with a function used later - what is the exact error message?

Comment: maybe one more thing to try/check: Expand References, Right Click on NReco, Select Properties, `Embed Interop Types`  - try this as True.  You have some other InterOp references, so if the prj is some sort of Office helper/plugin/extension maybe that will work.  I had to do that to get a DLL to work with something recently.

Comment: I tried that too but it gave me this message: Interop type 'HtmlToPdfConverter' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could figure out why NReco wasn't working, but I did find a pretty awesome alternative that works very well.

Nuget Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pechkin/

Source Code: https://github.com/gmanny/Pechkin

This library uses WebKit Engine to convert HTML to PDF and it does a very nice job of rendering things correctly thanks to WebKit.

It is relatively easy to use and it is free to use under the creative commons license. I highly recommend this library for anybody wanting this functionality for free.